# How to check if respberry pi is connected to internet from a website using php?

Tags: php, python

I am trying to make a web based home appliance automation project taking reference from [here](https://diyhacking.com/raspberry-pi-home-automation/).

I am using:

- RPi 3 modal B.
- Website hosted on free-hosting website (000webhost).
- PHP 
  -Python

I want to implement following more things in this:

- Before activating on and off button, i want to check if the raspberry pi is on and online running python script to check if any command is provided to it, if on then only the ON and OFF button are in focus.

  - Since the webpage and the RPi is communicating by writing to and reading from text file, it is possible that pi turns off (due to power failure) causing the appliance to turn off but the file still contains status 'ON'. I want to check every 2-3 seconds if pi is online and working so that i can display on the website that the appliance is currently working and if pi get turned off i can display "There is some problem with Pi, check out."

I searched the web for the same but I am not getting any solution using PHP so that i can continuously check the status of my pi.
I got a solution to use cron jobs but no any free hosting website provide cron job that repeat every 2-3 seconds and the minimum time is 10 min.

1. Is there any way to check continuously if Pi is online from the website?
2. One I think is Pi itself show its online status by writing to another file but how will I make my webpage to check that file continuously  or is there better method?
3. I will appreciate if I get any more suggestions to make this project better.

NOTE: I can only upload files on the website, i don't have any means to provide command to the server.

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you try to query the pi and it doesn't respond, then it is off-line. If you want to continually query it, you could use Javascript timers to make ajax calls to the pi every 2 or 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I entirely follow the architecture but you could look at the modified data of the file. Another thing that comes to mind is to have the Pi write a timestamp to the file instead of "ON". Using this timestamp, you will know when the file was last written and if it is more than X time old, assume the Pi is off. But you will have to make sure the clocks are all close.